# unable to find valid certification path to requested target - link to github

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, ssl

A spring mvc app use mvc
when I run the config-server, and try to go to the target (github link) with browser address: HTTP://localhost:8888/servise-a/master
in the browser I get 404 error,-
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jan 20 10:38:56 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

and in the consul there are errors-

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/ronykeren/cloud: Secure connection to https://github.com/ronykeren/cloud could not be stablished because of SSL problems
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:254) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/ronykeren/cloud: Secure connection to https://github.com/ronykeren/cloud could not be stablished because of SSL problems
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.handleSslFailure(TransportHttp.java:632) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:583) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:362) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:137) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:123) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1271) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:243) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      ...
```

the program is very simple,
the main app included just the start with spring application:

```
package main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;


@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigureServerApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigureServerApp.class);
    }
}
```

the configuration with application.yml file:

```
spring:
 cloud:
   config:
     server:
       git:
         uri: https://github.com/ronykeren/cloud

server:
 port: 8888
```

and pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
           <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the stacktrace is quite explicite :

> Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/ronykeren/cloud: Secure connection to https://github.com/ronykeren/cloud could not be stablished because of SSL problems

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

In fact, the config server will try to contact your Git repo but is not able to do it because the lack of a valid certificate in your JVM.
I think the answer here : ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ) is adapted for your problem.